# Ui Router 1.0, Pass parameters through ui-sref

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

In the new `angular-ui-router@1.0.0-beta.3` I'm trying to pass parameters through `ui-sref`.

Example: `ui-sref="login({tab : 'client'})"`

This is not working in the subsequent components controller.

ex:

```js
class LoginController {
  static $inject = ['$stateParams', '$transitions'];
  constructor(private _$stateParams, private _$transitions) {}
  $onInit(){
    console.log('stateParams:', this._$stateParams);
    console.log('$transitions:', this._$transitions);
    this._$transitions.onSuccess({}, ($transition$) => {
         console.log('$transition$ params:', $transition$.params());
    });
  }
}
```

I understand that `$stateParams` is deprecated.

I also understand that `$transitions` is the way to go.

I still cannot find the params in either of those objects.

I can access them (yes the controller is running, $onInit is running, etc), but they don't have the required data

Any help?

Comment: What is your console says?

Comment: `stateParams: t {#: null}` |||||||
`$transitions: t {_router: t, $view: t, _deregisterHookFns: Object}` |||||||
`$transition$ params: Object {#: null}`

Comment: can you create a plnkr?

Comment: It's class. Not classes